# Register model in sagemaker with terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to register a model in model package group using terraform.

I referred following links:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_model

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_model_package_group

I was able to create a SageMaker Model Package Group using second link. But no information on how to register/add model in this Model Package Group.